# ¿Porque me sale el error int object no iterable en este caso?

Tags: python-3.9

*En el siguiente trozo de codigo Released date es un dato de fecha %d/%/%Y de un fichero csv, quiero que si en los parametros de la funcion la inicial o final es none, se convierte en el año maximo o minimo de released date, pero al ejecutarlo me da int object no iterable.*

```
def pokemons_por_tipo(pokemons, fecha_inicial=None, fecha_final=None):
    
    for p in pokemons:
        if fecha_inicial==None:
            fecha_inicial=min(p.Released_Date.year)
        if fecha_final==None:
            fecha_final=max(p.Released_Date.year)
        pokemons_filtrados=[p for p in pokemons if fecha_inicial<= p.Released_Date.year<=fecha_final]
    return pokemons_filtrados
```

Comment: Que tipo de dato es `pokemons`? Si es un entero pues ahí esta el error, no puedes ietrara en un entero, se itera en un rango `range(pokemons)`

Comment: Estas ocupando la misma variable `p`  en dos ciclos anidados.